# Memory management in game development?

Tags: android, memory

I'm new to android and i started to develop a game, I thought about memory management when loading images and using them for animations, I want to know how to manage it properly so it wont damage the game's smoothness, How could i proceed with this?. And while I'm asking about game development is it a good idea to start with a new framework for all the calculations,physics and graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start gaming development on Android, I recommend you use a game framework built on top of OpenGL-es

Look into LibGdx, it s a great starting point, so you don't reinvent the wheel and get productive right away:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: ill try the framework but is LibGdx is a good library to learn from it too?,because i don't want to do the frameworks function without understanding want they are doing fully, thats how i want to learn from scrach

Comment: I think it s perfect for your case, it's built over openGl so you can always dig deeper as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to memory management in Android, the thing to keep in mind is that Java has automatic garbage collection. So, as long as you don't maintain a reference to images and animations after they're no longer needed, they will get garbage collected and removed from memory as needed.

The Android Developer docs contain much information related to memory management and performance: http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html

Another thing to keep in mind is that the complexity of your layouts has a dramatic effect on app performance. Try to keep your layouts as flat as reasonably possible. This is explained here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: in android game development are layouts and views used or its all drawn and with functionality inside a component that i create?

Comment: It depends on what route you choose to go with for game development. You may choose a framework that has its own method of handling animation. I was just speaking to the first part of your question, native Android images/animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new you definitely shouldnt start off by making your own framework bro, its just way too ambitious.

Go for OpenGL or a library like that as the other answer said for a game with 3D graphics, or even no graphics framework if its a very simple game that doesnt need that. It really depends on the kind of game you have in mind.

Check this for memory management tips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McAvq5SkeTk

What will matter the most though is optimizing the animations for smoothness, check this for tips on this and general guidelines for what you want: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I enjoyed using [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) to develop mobile games. It will handle those types of memory issues for you.